# What is cp Command to copy all files + directory structure AND cp Command to skip copying files when they already exist

Tags: cp, macos, file-copy

I need to copy all of the files in a directory while preserving the directory structure to a backup hard drive. Will this work:

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec cp --parents \{\} /target \;
```

Then I want to copy the backup hard drive to a new computer, but if the file already exists at the target location I don't want to copy it, I just want to skip it.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `find` and `cp` combo. I would use `rsync` for such a task.

To copy 'everything' and preserve permissions and ownership (and skip what need not be copied), use for example a 'dry run'

```
sudo rsync -Havn sourcedir/ targetdir/
```

and when things look good remove the `n` and do the real copying,

```
sudo rsync -Hav sourcedir/ targetdir/
```

The slash ending `sourcedir/` is important, which is described in `man rsync`.

If you have no hard links you can skip `H`, and the search process will be faster.

If there is no problem with permissions and ownership, you can run the `rsync` command line without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

just check with your man page of cp
but the -n flag should do the trick.

```
find . -name '.' -exec cp -n --parents {} /target ;
```

-n    Do not overwrite an existing file.

but please check with your system, and make a test.

On cp i may think about adding -p flag to preserve modification time and access time
but it will preserve many other file system informations that you may don' want to keep like permissions, ACL, owners...

i would write '{}' instead of just {} and close the instruction with ;

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec cp -n --parents '{}' /target \;
```

Comment: `-name '.'` was a formatting issue, it's actually `-name '*.*'`

Comment: thanks for the comment, i have updated my answer and added some pieces of advice based of my own experience